# Attempting to modify object outside of a write transaction

Tags: ios, iphone, realm

I am trying to retrieve all the saved User (RLMObject) objects. Then i check if there are any objects saved. If not i create a new User object and try to save it.

```
  RLMArray *allUsers = [User allObjects];

 if (allUsers.count == 0) {
      RLMRealm *realm = [RLMRealm defaultRealm];
      [realm beginWriteTransaction];

      User *newUser = [[User alloc]init];
      newUser.userID = [userDict[@"id"] integerValue];
      newUser.role = userDict[@"role"];
      newUser.email = userDict[@"email"];
      newUser.given_name = userDict[@"profile"][@"given_name"];
      newUser.family_name = userDict[@"profile"][@"family_name"];

      [realm addObject:newUser];
      [realm commitWriteTransaction];

  }
```

However this crashes with the message: `'RLMException', reason: 'Attempting to modify object outside of a write transaction - call beginWriteTransaction on a RLMRealm instance first.'`

I don't really know why. I am modifying the object inside a write transaction on the default realm.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are you sure that's where the app is crashing?

Comment: @trojanfoe You're right that wasn't the place where it crashed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nevermind, my stupid mistake. Thanks @trojanfoe for the heads up.

I was downloading an image on the background thread and store it in a Realm on completion. Looks like calling `defaultRealm` second time return a different instance.

Comment: defaultRealm will always return the same path, but a different instance for each thread on which it's called. Tim's answer was correct.

Comment: @jpsim Sorry, that's what i wanted to say. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

You must call RLMRealm defaultRealm once per thread, to obtain a different RLMRealm instance (same file path, but different variable). This allows us to keep all the thread-safety sorted out easily for you. See http://realm.io/docs/cocoa/0.84.0/#using-a-realm-across-threads for details.